# how to add button value to django form field when button pressed

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I want to add the value of the button value to the "{{form.token}}" field when the button is pressed

```
 <form>
  {%csrf_token%}
  {{form.name}}
  {{form.mobile}}
  <button type="button" value="1" id="one">
  <button type="button" value="2" id="two">
  **{{form.token}}**
</form>
```

Comment: At least show some code....

Comment: you have to handle that functionality with javascript.